# Vim - Mimic ZenCoding/Emmet for other languages (like ZenSharp for C#)?

Tags: vim, vsvim

I have only tried Vim a few times, and am thinking of jumping in fully, but I was wondering if it had a feature similar to ZenSharp for ReSharper?

Eg. if I type `ppiCount+` it would expand to:
`public int Count { get; set; }`

You use similar mnemonics for properties, fields, and classes. It's based on ZenCoding/Emmet.

Unfortunately I don't know much about Vim at all so I didn't get too far with googling. Would something like Vim macros work here? Or a Vim plugin like YouCompleteMe?

FYI, I'm going to be using VsVim for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

VsVim doesn't support the macro language of Vim.  VsVim gives you a lot of the editing goodness of Vim, I have a guide ( a little out of date now, I'm looking to completely rewrite it at some point! ) here https://github.com/keithn/vsvimguide that shows how to try and make R# and VsVim work together ( or at least give ideas on how you might want to customize it )

The big thing is, you can mix in VsVim with other third party plugins, however sometimes there are weird conflicts depending on how the thirdparty thing works.  However you can make vim bindings to plugins to get a more "vim" like experience, my article shows how to do that for R# commands.

So VsVim doesn't replace things like R# and other useful plugins, however sometimes they don't play nicely together, so you should be able to keep using ZenSharp.   If it was the REAL Vim, then yes, you could use the macro language ( or find pre done plugins for Vim ) to do snippets on steroids.

Comment: What do you mean by macro language of vim? Vim has macros and a scripting language, neither of which the answer touches on. The answer is almost certainly theres a plugin, or that you would need to write one. There is an emmet plugin for html, but ive never tried it.